# Make clock running

Tags: javascript, refresh, clock

I would like the time to reset every second so the clock becomes a running one. I'm a javascript noob and I couldn't find any solution anywhere.

```
        <!--
        var currentDate = new Date()
        var day = currentDate.getDate()
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
        document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")
        //-->
    <!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()


if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

if (seconds < 10)
seconds = "0" + seconds


document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds)
```

Comment: try `window.setInterval`

Comment: What you need is running it each second. So try use setInterval(function(){ //your code here},1000);

Answer (score 1):

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
  window.document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}, 1000);
```

Later you can stop it with

```
window.clearInterval(myInterval);
```

We assign the return value of setInterval (an ID in the form of a number) to a variable because we'll need it later to stop our particular interval using the clearInterval function. If we don't do that, there will be no way (without certain hacks) to stop the interval.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use the `window.setInterval` method. Please look at this page for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp